# Navigation Drawer обработка переходов из итемов

Tags: android, listview, android-fragment, android-navigation-drawer

Подошел к моменту, когда пора начать писать переходы из итемов `drawer` для перехода на необходимые активити. Но поскольку самоучка и это мой первый "боевой" проект, то я полез искать в сети реализации - и они везде используют [практику](http://www.fandroid.info/kak-sdelat-navigation-drawer-v-android/) с `listView`.

На данный момент у меня имеется лишь следующий код:

```
  private void initNavigationDrawer() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigationView);

        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.open_drawer, R.string.close_drawer);
        //    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.hamburger);

        toggle.syncState();

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    }
```

и

```
  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id) {

            case R.id.recent_activity:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, RecentActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
        }

        return true;
    }
```

При этом новая активити не появляется. Если быть точнее - она заслоняется пустым "заслоном".

Вопрос в том, только ли через `listView` и отдельный класс-обработчик `drawer` делается переход в пунктах меню, какие бывают подводные камни (при поворотах, возможно?), стоит ли использовать фрагменты или неоправданно?

Желательно какой-то минимальный код, без которого ни один `drawer` не обойдется, минимальный функционал.

Comment: А если при создании `intent` заменить `this` на `YourActivity.this`?

Comment: А актвити эта прописана в манифесте?

Comment: Во-первых, с drawer'ом лучше пользоваться фрагментами. А ещё лучше вообще всегда пользоваться фрагментами. Во-вторых, [Creating a Navigation Drawer](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html), раздел "Handle Navigation Click Events".

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да, прописана